# React MUI component to HTML string

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf, material-ui, html-to-pdf

How can I conver the MUI component to html string, so all the styles we be included as well?
My main goal is to create a dynamic template form and to save as PDF file on server side.
i'm trying to send the component as html string, in order to generate PDF file. There is only one problem, all mui styles got lost in pdf file

This is what I'm doing now:

client:

```
     const formTemplate = (user)=>{
    return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item lg={4} xs={12}>
       <TextField fullWidth 
         defaultValue={user.firstName} label={"First Name"} />
       </Grid>
      <Grid item lg={4} xs={12}>
       <TextField fullWidth 
         defaultValue={user.familyName} label={"FamilyName"} />
       </Grid>
    </Grid>)
}

function saveForm(user){
 const formTamplate = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(formTemplate(user))
 try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${url}/consent/sign`, {
        email: user.email,
        formTamplate: formTamplate
      });
  
      dispatch({
        type: ActionType.setEnvelopeInfo,
        payload: {
          envelope: response.data.envelope,
           },
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
}
```

server:

```
router.post("/sign", async (req, res) => { 
  const { email, formTamplate } = req.body; 
  const formTemplatePath = `${signed_docs}\\${name}.pdf`;
  let options = { format: "A4" };
  let file = { content: formTamplate};
  try {
    await html_to_pdf.generatePdf(file, options).then((pdfBuffer: any) => {
      console.log({ pdfBuffer: pdfBuffer });
      console.log(typeof pdfBuffer);
      fs.writeFile(formTemplatePath, pdfBuffer, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log({ files_err: err });
          return;
        }
      });
      console.log("PDF Buffer:-", pdfBuffer);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log({ pdf_err: err });
  }
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Button, Box, Link, Typography, Grid } from '@mui/material'
import ReactToPrint from 'react-to-print';

function App() {
  const reference = useRef();
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={()=>{
        console.log(reference.current)
        }}>ref</Button>
      <Box sx={{textAlign:'center'}}>
        <ReactToPrint 
        trigger={() => <Link>Print</Link>}
        content={() => reference.current!}/>

        {/* Place the component here and set the reference */}
        <Box ref={reference} sx={{textAlign:"center"}}>
          <br/>
          
          <Typography variant='h4'>Booking details</Typography>
          <Grid container direction="column" spacing={1}>
            <Grid container item direction="row" justifyContent='space-around'>
              <Typography variant="body1" color="initial">VAT</Typography>
              <Typography variant="body1" color="initial">$XXX</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container item direction="row" justifyContent='space-around'>
              <Typography variant="body1" color="initial">VAT</Typography>
              <Typography variant="body1" color="initial">$XXX</Typography>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Box>
      </Box>
      </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

console.log(reference.current) logs this output
[click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alvvx.png)

useRef hook can be used and the reference has that everything converted to html.

suggestion: react-to-print can be used to directly convert mui components easily, have a look into it. Hope this helps!